# GCP: Change OAuth Client ID referred to by IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

In a GCP project, a App Engine IAP is now configured with one OAuth2 Client ID.
I need to point this IAP to another OAuth2 Client ID.
Is there a way to change the OAuth2 Client ID that this App Engine IAP is referring to now?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that. As per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#authorization):

> When you turn on IAP for a resource, it automatically creates an OAuth
> 2.0 client ID and secret. If you delete the automatically generated OAuth 2.0 credentials, IAP won't function correctly. You can view and
> manage OAuth 2.0 credentials in the Cloud Console APIs & services.

If you go to APIs & Services > Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy API > Credentials and try to edit credentials platform allows only delete and reset it, but you cannot change Client ID